# gBrowser.addEventListener: "load" event fired three times

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, onload

I have installed the "hello world" dev example for Firefox extensions as described here:
http://blog.mozilla.com/addons/2009/01/28/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/

I have modified the anonymous function that gets passed to gBrowser.addEventListener:

```
gBrowser.addEventListener("load", function (event) {

    var t = event.target;
    alert("Content title: " + t.contentTitle);          

}, false);
```

This function is getting called three times for every page load. When I click a link, it fires twice for the current (already loaded page) and once for the new page.

I have uninstalled all other addons (including Firebug) and still it fires 3 times. Does anyone know why this might be?

Thanks Richard

Comment: I think this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470961/onload-called-multiple-times-from-firefox-extension/

Comment: yes it is. and your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to do something like this:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function load() {
                    window.removeEventListener("load",load,false); //no longer needed
                    window.gBrowser.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function load(event) {
                    your_addon.init_function(event);
                    }, false);
```

In my addon it works. :-)

Hope this helps.

Michał